# User wants to post link to their facebook wall

Tags: php, facebook

Our early users want to post links to their artifacts onto their facebook wall.  Not something we put in the beta version.

This site lets users post photos and descriptions (artifacts from antiquity) and instead of referring people to our site they prefer posting a link to their 2nd century b.c. ornaments' photos onto their facebook wall.

I will add a button 'FB' on our site -- they click the button and (somehow) a 'log in to facebook' window appears so they can immediately put the link on our site of their antique onto their wall.

I have studied this on SO and read posts on 'share,' 'like,' the FB sdk docs, the 'graph api', but it all seems like not what I need to do, which is simple -- add a FB button on our site that when clicked lets them log on to their Facebook account so they can put the link on their wall.

Surely this is a solved problem -- or is it?

Answer (score 1):

You do want to use the FB API's Share button.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

Specifically, you'll want a button like:

```
<a name="fb_share"
    url="<?php echo "//" + $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>"
></a> 
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[Edit]
As discussed in the comments, Share is deprecated. Here is the like code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=<?php echo $APP_ID; ?>";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like"
    data-href="<?php echo "//" + $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>"
    data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

And on closer examination, this is the code I'm currently using on my content network; I'd forgotten this was the new version.

Comment: Thanks Dave, it leads you to using the 'Like' button -- all I want is a button on my site that when clicked on, displays a 'log in to your Facebook account' window or dialog.

Comment: If you want a link to the page to appear on a user's timeline, you want to use the "Share" button- it lets them post a URL to their timeline, a friend's timeline, add comments, and all the other things you get when you click "Share" on a news feed. Like will also show up on their timeline, but will not let them add comments directly. If you want to redirect them to Facebook and have them copy and paste the link by hand, you could redirect them to facebook.com, or use the Share or Like APIs. From what you said, I think you really do want the Share button. It's what all the other sites use.

Comment: Agreed but Facebook has deprecated Share as mentioned at the top of the link you provided - basically Share is history at this point.

Comment: Hah! Facebook deprecates APIs faster than I can read their blog describing new ones.